# Woocommerce Order API Line Item ID changes on update

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I’m retrieving Woocommerce orders via the "order updated" webhook and storing specific data in a separate database.

We are also using a personalisations plugin which allows customers to add custom messages to products. This creates 2 separate line items, which would otherwise be the same product variation in the backend.

On my separate database, when creating or updating a row, I need to use **order_id**, **variation_id** as well as the **id** entry (from line_items => id) to check whether a record must be created or updated. This ensure that 2 identical product variations with separate custom messages aren't overwritten by each other.

On order create the following JSON response is sent.

```
{"id":10656,"parent_id":0,"number":"10656","order_key":"wc_order_5a9815fa1add6","created_via":"checkout","version":"3.1.2","status":"pending","currency":"ZAR","date_created":"2018-03-01T17:02:18","date_created_gmt":"2018-03-01T15:02:18","date_modified":"2018-03-01T17:02:18","date_modified_gmt":"2018-03-01T15:02:18","discount_total":"0.00","discount_tax":"0.00","shipping_total":"0.00","shipping_tax":"0.00","cart_tax":"60.79","total":"495.00","total_tax":"60.79","prices_include_tax":true,"customer_id":5148,"customer_ip_address":"197.89.123.74","customer_user_agent":"mozilla\/5.0 (linux; android 6.0.1; samsung sm-g900h build\/mmb29k) applewebkit\/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) samsungbrowser\/6.4 chrome\/56.0.2924.87 mobile safari\/537.36","customer_note":"","billing":{"first_name":"Tasneem","last_name":"Modack","company":"","address_1":"","address_2":"","city":"","state":"","postcode":"","country":"ZA","email":"modackt@webmail.co.za","phone":"0828736647"},"shipping":{"first_name":"Tasneem","last_name":"Modack","company":"","address_1":"","address_2":"","city":"","state":"","postcode":"","country":"ZA"},"payment_method":"payfast","payment_method_title":"Pay With Your Card or Instant EFT.","transaction_id":"","date_paid":null,"date_paid_gmt":null,"date_completed":null,"date_completed_gmt":null,"cart_hash":"666062e6d9100aa43860fb71caef1466","meta_data":[{"id":506232,"key":"_store_location","value":"loop-street-cbd"},{"id":506233,"key":"_collection_date","value":"3 March, 2018"},{"id":506234,"key":"_collection_time","value":"10:00 AM"},{"id":506235,"key":"mailchimp_woocommerce_is_subscribed","value":"1"},{"id":506259,"key":"_billing_vat_number","value":""}],"line_items":[{"id":28607,"name":"Rainbow - Yes (add R50.00)","product_id":415,"variation_id":2590,"quantity":1,"tax_class":"","subtotal":"434.21","subtotal_tax":"60.79","total":"434.21","total_tax":"60.79","taxes":[{"id":1,"total":"60.79","subtotal":"60.79"}],"meta_data":[{"id":194971,"key":"transform-into-a-pinata","value":"Yes (add R50.00)"}],"sku":"N005-P","price":434.21,"_product_group":"rainbow-cakes"}],"tax_lines":[{"id":28609,"rate_code":"ZA-VAT-1","rate_id":1,"label":"VAT","compound":false,"tax_total":"60.79","shipping_tax_total":"0.00","meta_data":[]}],"shipping_lines":[{"id":28608,"method_title":"Local pickup","method_id":"local_pickup:10","total":"0.00","total_tax":"0.00","taxes":[],"meta_data":[{"id":194976,"key":"Items","value":"Rainbow - Yes (add R50.00) × 1"}]}],"fee_lines":[],"coupon_lines":[],"refunds":[]}
```

The line_item => id, when the order is created is **28607**

On order update the following JSON response is sent.

```
{"id":10656,"parent_id":0,"number":"10656","order_key":"wc_order_5a9815fa1add6","created_via":"checkout","version":"3.1.2","status":"pending","currency":"ZAR","date_created":"2018-03-01T17:02:18","date_created_gmt":"2018-03-01T15:02:18","date_modified":"2018-03-01T17:02:18","date_modified_gmt":"2018-03-01T15:02:18","discount_total":"0.00","discount_tax":"0.00","shipping_total":"0.00","shipping_tax":"0.00","cart_tax":"60.79","total":"495.00","total_tax":"60.79","prices_include_tax":true,"customer_id":5148,"customer_ip_address":"197.89.123.74","customer_user_agent":"mozilla\/5.0 (linux; android 6.0.1; samsung sm-g900h build\/mmb29k) applewebkit\/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) samsungbrowser\/6.4 chrome\/56.0.2924.87 mobile safari\/537.36","customer_note":"","billing":{"first_name":"Tasneem","last_name":"Modack","company":"","address_1":"","address_2":"","city":"","state":"","postcode":"","country":"ZA","email":"modackt@webmail.co.za","phone":"0828736647"},"shipping":{"first_name":"Tasneem","last_name":"Modack","company":"","address_1":"","address_2":"","city":"","state":"","postcode":"","country":"ZA"},"payment_method":"payfast","payment_method_title":"Pay With Your Card or Instant EFT.","transaction_id":"","date_paid":null,"date_paid_gmt":null,"date_completed":null,"date_completed_gmt":null,"cart_hash":"666062e6d9100aa43860fb71caef1466","meta_data":[{"id":506232,"key":"_store_location","value":"loop-street-cbd"},{"id":506233,"key":"_collection_date","value":"3 March, 2018"},{"id":506234,"key":"_collection_time","value":"1:00 PM"},{"id":506235,"key":"mailchimp_woocommerce_is_subscribed","value":"1"},{"id":506256,"key":"_billing_vat_number","value":""}],"line_items":[{"id":28604,"name":"Rainbow - Yes (add R50.00)","product_id":415,"variation_id":2590,"quantity":1,"tax_class":"","subtotal":"434.21","subtotal_tax":"60.79","total":"434.21","total_tax":"60.79","taxes":[{"id":1,"total":"60.79","subtotal":"60.79"}],"meta_data":[{"id":194951,"key":"transform-into-a-pinata","value":"Yes (add R50.00)"}],"sku":"N005-P","price":434.21,"_product_group":"rainbow-cakes"}],"tax_lines":[{"id":28606,"rate_code":"ZA-VAT-1","rate_id":1,"label":"VAT","compound":false,"tax_total":"60.79","shipping_tax_total":"0.00","meta_data":[]}],"shipping_lines":[{"id":28605,"method_title":"Local pickup","method_id":"local_pickup:10","total":"0.00","total_tax":"0.00","taxes":[],"meta_data":[{"id":194956,"key":"Items","value":"Rainbow - Yes (add R50.00) × 1"}]}],"fee_lines":[],"coupon_lines":[],"refunds":[]}
```

The line_item => id, when the order is updated is **28604**

This will create an additional line item in the order on my system when in fact it is the same line item.

Is there a reason why this happens, and is there a possible workaround?

**NOTE**
Dropping the rows and re-adding is not an options as the database on my system contains separate columns that are not related to Woocommerce.

**UPDATE**
According to the JSON response, specifically the **"date_created"**, it appears that the "order created" webhook fires twice but on "order updated" it only fires once.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why there's an order update being sent?  Would you not get all the information from the initial order create event?

Comment: @AndrewSchultz My Laravel app frequently updates the order status which in turn fires the "order updated" webhook.

Comment: Are you using laravel together with wordpress? Can you explain what is a "line_item"? Also, it would be helpful to see the code producing this behaviour..

Comment: @Yuri do you have any experience with Woocommerce?

Comment: "*We are also using a personalisations plugin which allows customers to add custom messages to products.*" — did you get the same issue *without* the plugin, or with the plugin disabled/deactivated? You can also view the data sent to the webhook's Delivery URL by going to [WooCommerce > Status > Logs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/webhooks/).

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely an issue with the personalization plugins you mentioned, because woocommerce on its own does not create a new line item on update as evident from the code below
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/api/legacy/v2/class-wc-api-orders.php#L867

```
protected function set_line_item( $order, $item, $action ) {
$creating  = ( 'create' === $action );
```

//

```
   if ( $creating ) {
      $line_item = new WC_Order_Item_Product();
    } else {
      $line_item = new WC_Order_Item_Product( $item['id'] );
    }
```

I would strongly recommend you to disable the customisation plugin and try.

Comment: I've had a look at the webhook logs and it appears that the order created webhook at times fires twice, even on orders that do not contain a personalised products. I have a method in my controller on the Laravel side, that is responsible for creating new orders. I'm essentially blocking order creation if the orders already exists. I'm busy testing to see if this works.

Comment: okay, Post the results as this question is very unique and i would be interested in the outcome.